# "be damned to" meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> "Curfew's been broken, you heard the noise," one of his companions told the barman. "Someone was out in the street against regulations -"
>
> "If I want to put my cat out, I will, and **be damned to** your curfew!"
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sub>

I only found [be damned](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/be%20damned). I don't quite get "be damned to". What does it mean?

A side: what does the whole sentence is saying? *"If I want to put my cat out, I will, and be damned to your curfew!"*

Comment: It means the same thing as "your curfew be damned."

Comment: It's like saying *"If I want to put ... and [I say] 'be damned!' to your curfew!"*

Comment: Aberforth Dumbledore made it up. He told the Death Eaters that it was him who broke the Caterwauling Charm (alarm/siren) by letting his cat out. And that he did not care about the curfew - if he wanted to let his cat out for its business, he would do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning is exactly the same as what you've linked to. The phrase here isn't "be damned to," it's just "be damned."

What's a bit unusual is that the speaker is essentially addressing the exclamation "be damned!" to "your curfew" rather than to another person. It's a bit of a figurative usage. We can imagine that the speaker is really talking to whomever is responsible for setting the curfew, but that person isn't actually present to hear them talk. The speaker is basically saying "I don't care about the curfew."

As for the whole sentence's meaning, "put my cat out" I think is just a way of saying letting the cat outside so it can run around or use the bathroom or whatever. The whole sentence would therefore be something along the lines of:

> If I want to let my cat outside, I will do so whether there is a curfew or not. I don't care about the curfew.